# C++ / syntax / addressing member function

Tags: c++, syntax

I've stumbled upon this code that really confuses me:

```
SomeObject->SomeFunction()->AnotherFunction(...);
```

What is the meaning of the second arrow `->` that follows the call to `SomeFunction()` member function?

P.S. `SomeFunction()` function is declared inside a class just like this:

```
const int * SomeFunction() {return ipValue;}
```

Comment: if SomeFunction returns int, that won't even compile

Comment: That should not compile, since an `int` does not have a `AnotherFuntion` member function.

Comment: Check again, SomeFunction must return a pointer to some class.

Comment: oh my bad, just edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeFunction()` returns a pointer to a class which has one of its methods (called `AnotherFunction`) invoked. If you break it up, it might look like this:

```
Object* obj = SomeObject->SomeFunction();
obj->AnotherFunction();
```

As already mentioned, if SomeFunction() returns an int* this won't work.

Comment: As already mentioned, if SomeFunction() returns an int* this won't work.

Comment: SomeFunction() returns a `const int*`. It's specified in the question.

Answer (score 3):

That's a compilation error.

`int` is a basic type, not a class, so you can't call methods on it.

This technique is called **method chaining**. You can call subsequent methods if the member function returns an object or a pointer to an object. In your case, it doesn't compile since the method returns an `int`. However, something like the following would work:

```
class A
{
public:
   A* foo();
   A* goo();
};

A* a = new A;
a->foo()->goo()->foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

It means, that the method `SomeFunction()` returns some kind of pointer or pointer-like object on which then in turn `AnotherFunction()` is called.

This means, that the `->` operator has exactely the same meaning, no matter, where it appears in your expressions.

**EDIT**:

Since the return type is `int` (before the edit)  the code will not compile as given. As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/9zCTr), the compiler complains about the operand to `->` not being a pointer. If you change the return type to a `int *` it still will not compile, since the operator `->` can only be invoked on pointers to class types, but not on pointers to fundamental types such as int. [Here](http://ideone.com/wB8AS) is an example with a `int *` and the appropriate error message.

Comment: Whoops, just noted the return type you gave for `SomeFunction()`. In that case there are many things wrong. This will not compile, and the `const` in the return type is absolutely meaningless to the compiler (but might sometimes be used as documentation).

Comment: And here is the proof, that it does not compile the way you described it: http://ideone.com/9zCTr

Comment: 2 reasons: 1. SomeFunction() doesn't return a pointer. 2. the `->` operator can be overloaded, so it's not necessary to have the same meaning, no matter what. If you correct the answer, I will happily remove the downvote.

Comment: @Luchian: Point 1 was mentioned in the comment, including a link to prove the comment. Also I was refering to a pointer or pointer like object (i.e. an object which has the -> operator overloaded). Furthermore I did not say that it has the same meaning "no matter what", but no matter where it appears. The syntax of the operator `->` is of course a very complicated matter in the presence of operator overloading, but this has nothing to do with the placement within the expression.

Comment: So... move it from the comment to the answer. Most people don't even read comments. "This means, that the -> operator has exactely the same meaning, no matter, where it appears in your expressions." - this is incorrect. If it appears after a pointer to an object that has the `->` overloaded, it has a different meaning than if it appears after an object that does not.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, I understood your point about the dependence on the type of the operand. But I was never refering to the type of the operand, but merely to the position. Since each type can appear at any position, it is positionally idependent. The dependence on the type is a completely different matter. I.e. in `a->b()->c()` both `->`have the meaning "look up the correct operator->() for `decltype(a) or decltype(a->b())` and use this operator". The first case may of course call a different of those operators, but still this is independent of the position where it appears.